# why does my directive hide the following elements?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Every time when I create a directive, I have to wrap it in some element, otherwise the following item won’t come, for example:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" >
    <div>
        <my-directive/>
    </div>
    <h1>abcd</h1>
</body>
```

The above works perfectly. But the h1 element didn’t come when div is not there:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" >
    <my-directive/>
    <h1>abcd</h1>
</body>
```

Do you have idea what is the issue?

I tried many AngularJs version: 1.2.7 and 1.2.29
They have the same issue.

Do I miss something?

Comment: Hi Justin! What element does your directive's template consist of?

Comment: I tried different elements in my directives, like <select... <fieldset ... , They all have the same trouble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<my-directive/>` is just not valid html.
Use:

```
<my-directive></my-directive>
```

instead.

Comment: It works, Thanks! But why <my-directive/> is invalid, I know many html tag use this way: <br/>

Comment: yes, <br/> is correct but i.e. <div/>, <span/>, <td/> are not